# Line separator between Header, Body and Footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a asp.net web form with a master page. I have three divs ... One with `class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"`, other with `class="main-content"` and the last one with `class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom"`.

I have now one little thing .. between divs separation line appears. How I can remove it? Thanks

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <img alt="Tu Conjunto" src="../../Imagenes/Img/General/Edificio_Trans2.png" style="position: absolute; top: -2px; right: 0;" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="IdButton" OnClick="IdButton_Click" Width="68" Height="56" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/Img/General/Exit4.png" style="position: absolute; top: -1px; left: -1px;" />
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server" Style="margin: 0px; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 13px;" runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Usuario Logueado">Bienvenido, <%: Session["NombreUsuario"]  %> !</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </asp:Panel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="main-content" style="border: none;">
    <div class="UnEspacioArriba30"></div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>


  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <p>&copy;
      <%: DateTime.Now.Year %>- My ASP.NET Application</p>
  </div>
```

Css is a Cerulean Theme from bootstrap.

Comment: Can you give us an example of your code so that we can further review it? Primarily the HTML objects and your CSS classes/selectors.

Comment: You need to post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS output). [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS after the CSS file of Bootstrap (on a own file or inline):

```
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border:0!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason maybe border or mostly padding an margin

```css
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    border:0!important;
    padding:0!important;
    margin:0!important;
}
/*for show*/
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    background:#00f;
}
.main-content {
    background:#0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">nav</div>
<div class="main-content">content</div>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">footer</div>
```